# VideoView does not play video when added to the Global Layout using WindowManager

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-windowmanager

I didn't find a similar question nor the answer to it, so I decided to post a new one.

I have created a custom RelativeLayout, which plays a role of a wrapper of the content layout which is inflated and added to the wrapper during the initialization of the so called wrapper.

And everything seems to be fine except for the video playback, in fact the video is not loaded at all(The onPrepared never gets called). I also tried listening for any errors that may have had something to do with it, but nothing was there either(OnError never gets called). The Log didn't contain any information that may've been related to this problem either.

It's a strange problem, as the VideoView works just fine in Activities, Fragments, etc. but when it comes to adding it to the global(system-wide) layout(using WindowManager) it starts to get really weird.

Is it even possible to play a video in the VideoView within the Global(System-wide) layout?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Code snippets:

CustomRelativeLayout

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {


public static final String TAG = "Some Tag";


public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}


//The rest of the constructors
//go here...


private void init() {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, false);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4"));
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.e(TAG, "The Video is ready to be played!");
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    //adding the inflated view
    addView(inflatedView);

    //adding to the windowManager
    Point size = new Point();
    mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        size.x,
        size.y
    );
    layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
    layoutParams.flags = (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    layoutParams.dimAmount = 0f;
    layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;

    mWindowManager.addView(this, layoutParams);
}
```

}

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, false);
  //you should add view i think 
addView(inflatedView);

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4"));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The Video is ready to be played!");
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: But the inflated view is added